# Random Quote Generator : Tweet Button with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a random quote generator. But I am not able to share it via twitter. I am getting a twitter page but the text box for the tweet is empty.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="div1">
  <p id="quote"></p>
  <p id="author"></p>
<button id="btn">getquote</button>
<div>
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet" target="_blank">
<button type="button" id="twitter-share-button">tweet</button>
</a>
  </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my Javascript code

```
var url1="http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&key=457653&format=jsonp&lang=en&jsonp=?";

//var url1=" http://date.jsontest.com/";


var getQuote=function(data){
    //console.log(data);
    var quot="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + data.quoteText+data.quoteAuthor;
    console.log(quot);

    $('#quote').text(data.quoteText);
    $('#author').text(data.quoteAuthor);
    $('#twitter-share-button').attr("href", quot);
};

$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON(url1,getQuote,'jsonp');

});
$("#btn").on("click",function(){
    $.getJSON(url1,getQuote,'jsonp');

});
```

I get the quote randomly but clicking on tweet button in my code doesnt change the `href` using `.attr` in Jquery. Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: How do you know that your `href` isn't being added? I've just made a very simple JSFiddle to show that your method should work perfectly fine: https://jsfiddle.net/errd1p37/1/. This also brings me to my next question: Why are you trying to add an `href` to a `button`?

Comment: `href` is added. I can see that in console. But when I click the button it goes to `https://twitter.com/intent/tweet` instead of `https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + data.quoteText+data.quoteAuthor`.So i don't get the tweet in the text box.

Comment: You're applying the `href` to the `<button>`, but what you should be applying it to is the `<a>`. Just change `$('#twitter-share-button').attr("href", quot);` to `$('#twitter-share-button').parent().attr("href", quot);`.

Comment: Thanks Santi. I was changing `href` of button which doesn't exist. But why did not it give an error in the console?

Comment: Your button exists! It's inside of your `<a>` tags: `<button type="button" id="twitter-share-button">tweet</button>`

Comment: But the button doesn't have an attribute called `href`.So I have to keep that in mind  or is there a way to get an error or warning?

Comment: If you do `.attr()` on an element, it either updates the attribute, or in the event it does not exist, it will be added. You can do `$element.attr("THIS-IS-A-MADE-UP-ATTRIBUTE", "Hello");` and it's perfectly valid. You just have to keep an eye out for it, there really is no error reporting if you've given the attribute to the wrong element. The best you can do is Right Click > Inspect Element.

Comment: Okay got it !!.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I'm just missing something, but it looks like you are trying to change the href attribute of the button, but the button doesn't have a href attribute (and probably shouldn't).

```
$('#twitter-share-button').attr("href", quot);
```

Instead you want to do

```
$('#twitter-share-anchor').attr("href", quot);
```

And give the actual anchor the id:

```
<a id="twitter-share-anchor" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet" target="_blank">
```

Comment: OH Yes!!. Thanks man. But why I did not get an error like"button doesn't have `href` attribute" or something like that? Can you please explain?

Comment: `href` is a legitimate attribute on any element, `<a>` elements are just the only one that will direct you to the `href` when clicked by default.

Comment: The reason you didn't get an error is because, in terms of coding, an error didn't actually occur: i.e. - you added a href attribute to a button element, which isn't the best thing to do in HTML terms but it also isn't 'invalid'. it's something you can do in jQuery, and it was being done. Secondly, you activated the Twitter link with the main URL of https://twitter.com/intent/tweet, and actually this is not an invalid action. You are allowed to use the twitter link with no variables appended, and some people want to do this because they want to go to a blank page, so it's a legitimate option.

Answer (score 0):

You're applying the `href` to the button, instead of its containing `<a>`. Because the `<a>` is the direct parent of your button, you can easily just change your `$('#twitter-share-button').attr("href", quot);` line to include a `.parent()`, like so:

```
$('#twitter-share-button').parent().attr("href", quot);
```